# Unable to install beautify plugin in Gimp 2.10.6

Tags: compiling, gimp

I use ubuntu 18.04.1
I've installed GIMP 2.10.6 using this PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp
I have tried to install beautify in several ways, using git and downloading the package but I came always with the same output... failed to make.

I download beautify from here... https://github.com/hejiann/beautify  and I place it in my home folder, it is named beautify-master I open it into a terminal and try to make but although I have libgimp2.0-dev in its latest version, 
"libgimp2.0 is already the newest version (2.10.6+om-0ubu18.04.2~ppa)".
 I receive this output...

```
~/beautify-master$ make
gcc `gimptool-2.0 --cflags` -c beautify.c -o beautify.o
Package gegl-0.4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gegl-0.4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'gegl-0.4', required by 'gimp-2.0', not found
No output from 'pkg-config --cflags gimpui-2.0'
beautify.c:18:10: fatal error: libgimp/gimp.h: No such file or directory
#include < libgimp/gimp.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 

compilation terminated.
Makefile:77: recipe for target 'beautify.o' failed
make: *** [beautify.o] Error 1
```

I also have tried to move the folder to my gimp plugin folder and tried to install it but didn't worked at all

I hope someone could tell me what I am doing wrong...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Might be an incompatability between the plugin and the new Gimp 2.10 version, which the developper of the plug-in will need to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libgimp%2Fgimp.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any) you need to install one package for `libgimp/gimp.h`:

```
sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev
```

If this is not enough then enable Source Code repositories in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and install build-dependencies of GIMP with:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gimp
```

and then compile the plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much I use your commands and finally worked... I post it for everyone who has the same problem...

Comment: Nice to hear! So you can accept the answer and/or vote for it :)

Comment: Glad to but I don't know how to do it... I look it around searching how to do it... thanks again

Comment: found it and dit it...

Answer (score 2):

I haven't installed libgegl-dev but I did it and then I use your two commands and was finally able to compile it using this...

```
git clone https://github.com/hejiann/beautify.git

cd beautify

make

make userinstall
```

and then I compiled textures...

```
$ cd /tmp/

$ wget https://github.com/hejiann/beautify/wiki/textures/rip-border-textures-0.5.1.tar.bz

$ wget https://github.com/hejiann/beautify/wiki/textures/texture-border-textures-0.5.1.tar.bz
```

and after this you should open your gimp and go to edit and then preferences and then folders and then pluguin folders and take note of your the first imput... in my case /home/18/.config/gimp/2.10/plug-ins 
and then...

```
cd /home/18/.config/gimp/2.10/plug-ins

tar xvf /tmp/rip-border-textures-0.5.1.tar.bz

tar xvf /tmp/texture-border-textures-0.5.1.tar.bz
```

And I have just installed not only beautify plugin but texture and borders...

Thank you so much Norbert... 
You make me my day... ver much happy...